# define variable with optional class type in if else statement

Tags: java

I need to change the class / stream type depending on whether a param (opath) is set, but when I declare in an if-else statement, netbeans complains that the variable oos cannot be found.

I don't understand this as the var oos is always set and there's no way that it is ever undefined ??

```
if(_param.get("opath") != null) {
    FileOutputStream oos = new FileOutputStream(_param.get("opath").toString());
} else {
    OutputStream oos = csocket.getOutputStream();
}

do something with oos...
```

Comment: It's out of scope. You need to declare it outside the `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you code to following

```
OutputStream oos;    
if(_param.get("opath") != null) {
    oos = new FileOutputStream(_param.get("opath").toString());
} else {
    oos = csocket.getOutputStream();
}
//do something with oos
```

It is just about scope and making the object available to the code where you want to use it

Answer (score 2):

local varibales's scope is limited it's definition block, in this case, the `if` or `else` block, so it's unaccessible from outside.

you can move it out:

```
OutputStream oos;

if(_param.get("opath") != null) {
    oos = new FileOutputStream(_param.get("opath").toString());
} else {
    oos = csocket.getOutputStream();
}

do something with oos...
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't encounter this issue using the [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) which is a "*shorthand for an if-then-else statement*":

```
OutputStream oos = _param.get("opath") != null ?
  new FileOutputStream(_param.get("opath").toString()) :
  csocket.getOutputStream();
```

In this case `oos` is declared and initialized at once.

Additionally this allows to define the variable `oos`even `final` which isn't possbile using the regular if-else-statement.